# matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 vs from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt, backend

What is the difference between

`matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5`

and

`matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg`?

It seems like they have somethings in common.

For example,

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as Navi_qt5
```

and

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as Navi_qt5agg
```

import the same method as shown by using

```
id(Navi_qt5)
```

and

```
id(Navi_qt5agg)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is a difference between `backend_qt5` and `backend_qt5agg`, the Navigation toolbar is the same in both cases. I.e. `backend_qt5agg` simply imports the `NavigationToolbar2QT` from `backend_qt5`.

The difference between the two backends `backend_qt5` and `backend_qt5agg` lies in the figure canvas. `matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg.FigureCanvasQTAgg` subclasses `matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5.FigureCanvasQT` and adds the Agg feature to it, which is the *antigrain (agg) rendering*. So essentially you cannot draw a figure with the `FigureCanvasQT` alone.

Hence, always use

```
matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg.FigureCanvasQTAgg
```

Comment: What if I didn't want to use the AGG renderer?  Would I use `matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5.FigureCanvasQT`?  Although from this page https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend it looks as if the only renderer for QT is AGG.

Comment: You have no choice. I mean, it does not make much sense to create a canvas, which cannot draw any figure because it's lacking the main method to do so, right? There is also not reason not to use the Qt5Agg renderer because it is supposed to draw the figure on screen; so nobody would acutally consider not to use it.